# How to evaluate multiple schemas with the same required keys using dependentSchema in JSON schema?

Tags: jsonschema

If I was expecting either one of these three objects without allowing any additional properties, how would I evaluate this in JSON schema? In it, a fruit can either be a real fruit, in which case it can contain the required "fruit" keyword alongside an optional keyword for its "weight", or a fruit can be a fake fruit, which requires the "plastic" keyword to describe what type of plastic it uses.

```
{
    "fruit": "apple"
}
```

or

```
{
    "fruit": "apple",
    "weight": 0.13145
}
```

or

```
{
    "fruit": "apple",
    "plastic": "polypropolene"
}
```

If I try to use the dependentSchema like so, plastic fruits obviously fail as it tries to match it against both schema since it also contains the "fruit" key. I can't find anywhere that tells me how to use if then statements to match schema depending on their keys, only their values, so I assume I have to figure out some way to make dependent schema work, right?

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "dependentSchemas": {
      "fruit": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required": "fruit",
        "properties": {
          "fruit": { "type": "string" },
          "diameter": { "type": "number" }
        }
      },
      "plastic": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "required": ["fruit", "plastic"],
        "properties": {
          "fruit": { "type": "string" },
          "plastic": { "type": "string" }
        }
      },
      "meat": { "$ref": "#/$defs/meat" },
      "bread": { "$ref": "#/$defs/bread" }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `oneOf` for the second property

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["fruit"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "fruit": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "weight": true,
    "plastic": true
  },
  "oneOf": [
    { 
       "type": "object",
       "required":["weight"],
       "properties": {
         "weight": {
           "type": "number"
         }
       }
    },
    {
       "type": "object",
       "required": ["plastic"],
       "properties": {
         "plastic": {
           "type": "string"
         }
       }
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works, though with the removal of weight being a required property since it's meant to be optional. Thanks!!

Comment: removing the `required: ["weight"]` breaks the `oneOf` validation because now the first oneOf schema is unconstrained, which means you can pass `plastic: true` or `plastic: 1` and it will pass validation.  You need to modify it a bit more to add `"not": { "required": ["plastic"]}}` to the first oneOf subschema. That should fix you right up.